# Understanding z3 bvsmod behavior with SSA

Tags: z3

I am trying to learn using z3. So this question might be silly.

Why do I get a unexpected values for x___0 from Z3 when I use bvsmod as compared to bvadd in the following code. I'm using SSA to implement execution flow here.

Z3 instructions:

```
(set-option :pp.bv-literals false)
;
; The code
;  x %= 5
;  x * 2 == 8
; Implement SSA
;  x1 = x0 % 5
;  x1 * 2 == 8
;
(push)
(set-info :status unknown)
(declare-const x___0 (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const x___1 (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (= x___1 (bvsmod x___0 (_ bv5 32))))
(assert (= (bvmul x___1 (_ bv2 32)) (_ bv8 32)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(pop)
;
; The code
;  x += 1
;  x * 2 == 8
; Implement SSA
;  x1 = x0 + 1
;  x1 * 2 == 8
;
(push)
(declare-const x___0 (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const x___1 (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (= x___1 (bvadd x___0 (_ bv1 32))))
(assert (= (bvmul x___1 (_ bv2 32)) (_ bv8 32)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(pop)
```

Results:

```
sat
(model 
    (define-fun x___1 () (_ BitVec 32)
        (_ bv4 32))
    (define-fun x___0 () (_ BitVec 32)
        (_ bv3720040335 32))
)
sat
(model 
    (define-fun x___1 () (_ BitVec 32)
        (_ bv4 32))
    (define-fun x___0 () (_ BitVec 32)
        (_ bv3 32))
)
```

In case of equation where I use bvadd x___0 get a value **3**, which makes sense.

Why do I get a value **3720040335** in case of bvsmod, which is no where near the expected value i.e. some value ending with 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the value you are getting. Your encoding is just fine.

Notice that you are using 32-bit signed integers (implicitly implied by the call to `bvsmod`.) The model returned gives you the value 32-bit bit-vector value whose decimal equivalent is `3720040335`. When interpreted as a signed-value, this is actually `-574926961`, and you can verify `(-574926961) % 5` indeed equals `4` as you requested.

Note that the solver is free to give you any model that satisfies your constraints. If you want a more specific value, you'll need to add additional constraints to encode what "simple" should formally mean.

Comment: I will add these constraints. `(assert (bvslt x___0 (_ bv5 32)))` and `(assert (bvsgt x___0 (_ bv0 32)))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the formula like that, you need quantifiers.
I suggest you use SMT expressions instead; sharing will happen for free.
write e.g.:
`(assert (= (bvmul (bvadd x___0 (_ bv1 32)) (_ bv2 32)) (_ bv8 32)))`

If you need the intermediate values, you can always later do an (eval ...)

Comment: Thanks. It will be helpful if you can give an example for using quantifiers to solve this problem.

Comment: Rewriting the SMT expressions in suggested way will work here. I'm afraid that it will be too complex for bigger blocks of C code that I want to convert into SMT expressions. Using SSA helps me there in two ways. 1. Implement execution flow. 2. Easier conversion of C code to SMT expression.

Comment: And I'm still wondering about the nature of `bvsmod` which results in the value which I'm getting as output of `(get-model)`.